# How to get id value from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get a most suitable photo of venues from Foursquare API, however, I cannot access **id** value of objects in the array.

I created a component for just getting a most suitable photo. My component takes venues as a prop and there is no problem at all. In React Development Tool, I can see all venues as a prop.

In componentDidMount():

```
fetch(
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${this.props.location.id}/photos? 
 limit=1&client_id=something&client_secret=something&v=20180726`
    )
```

However here this.props.location id is undefined. When I try to put a venue id by manual it works. I have a lot of venues and I need to get a photo of each one. 
in App.js:

`<MyComponent location={this.state.places} />`

You can be sure MyComponent location is not empty at all.

1. How can I access the id property properly?
2. When I try to get photos manually, many of the photos are not exactly related to venue, how can I select the best photo that represents the venue?

**Edit:**
Now I can access the id value of the objects, however, many of the photos are not exactly related to venue, how can I get the **most suitable** photo from the Foursquare api?

Comment: How/where is `props` being set? Can you add that code to the question?

Comment: @ColinYoung my component takes location={this.state.places} in my main component.

Comment: @Opsional please don't be sarcastic. Ask politely and respect Code of Conduct. Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: @Opsional not funny. Look at the mirror if you want to have fun.

Comment: I figured out my first question and edited to my post above. How can I get the **most suitable** photo of the venues from the Foursquare API?

Comment: you should only ask one thing in one question. If you are stuck with another loosely related concern, you should create a new question. Also, please select the best answer for this question.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I found the solution on my own, so I will not choose your answer as the best answer. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: That was not my message, or it was far less important message. But I've received your message, nothing to do here. Bye.

Comment: No problem ;) @NurbolAlpysbayev

Answer (score 1):

I bet `this.state.places` is an array. Which means, `this.props.location` is also an array. Which means you are querying `id` property from the array (`this.props.location`). You should write something like

```
<MyComponent location={this.state.places[0]} />
```

or

```
<MyComponent location={this.state.places[current]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should either access the props inside the render() or use the life cycle method getDerivedStateFromProps() and compare previous state against the new one. [Have a look at the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)